# Conditionally replacing strings in Pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

In my Pandas DataFrame, one of the columns- 'naics', contains NAICS codes such as 311, 311919, 3159, 331, 332, 332913.

I would like to replace all of the codes that begin with the same two digits with those two digits only. As an example, if the value is either 311, 311919, 3159 or any other string (these need to stay strings, not int) that starts with 31, I would like the new value to be 31.

I've tried variations of:

```
df.naics.loc[(df['naics'] == '^31')] = '31'
```

But every variation I've tried has not impact (and none have thrown errors).

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Jarod

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just slight change to your code, you won't need astype(str) if the column is of type object

```
df.loc[df['naics'].astype(str).str[:2] == '31', 'naics'] = '31'


naics
0   31
1   31
2   31
3   331
4   332
5   332913
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Worked great. I ended up using this solution because I was able to chain together conditions. Just one question, when I changed together conditions, I had to delete 'naics' after '31',. What does placing 'naics' in that spot do? Thanks again!

Comment: You are creating a slice using loc, the first part is the condition which will give you the rows and 'naics' is the column to which you are assigning a new value

Comment: This is excellent. I made it into a function here:     
    `def str_replace(df, s, sh, col, term):
        df.loc[s.str.contains('|'.join([sh])), col] = term; return df`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `str` accessor:

## setup:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'naics':['311', '311919', '3159', '331', '332', '332913']})
>>> df
    naics
0     311
1  311919
2    3159
3     331
4     332
5  332913
```

## Solution using `str`:

```
df['code'] = df.naics.str[:2]

>>> df
    naics code
0     311   31
1  311919   31
2    3159   31
3     331   33
4     332   33
5  332913   33
```

Comment: This is what I'd do.  However, what if string has length less than 2.  `df['code'] = df.naics.str[:2][df.naics.str.len() > 1]`

Comment: In that case, the code returned would just be that single character with my code, or `NaN` with your addition. I'm not sure what OP would want, but since they didn't specify...

Answer (score 2):

Using `startswith`

```
df.loc[df.naics.str.startswith('31'),'naics']='31'
df
Out[1272]: 
    naics
0      31
1      31
2      31
3     331
4     332
5  332913
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'naics':['311', '311919', '3159', '331', '332', '332913']})
df['code'] = df2.naics.apply(lambda s : s[:2])
df
```

Answer (score 0):

Credit to Vaishali for the original form. This for a more generalized function:

```
def str_replace(df, s, short, col, term): 
    df.loc[s.str.contains('|'.join([short])), col] = term
    return df
```

Here the dataframe (df) is sent into the function, the particular series (s), the short version of the string you want to capture, the column (col) name, and the term you want in its place. This then returns the dataframe.

I was able to do this iteratively as well, using a loop with two equal length lists zipped together; shrt a list for the capture terms, and trm a list for the new terms.

```
df = [str_replace( df, s, sh, col, t) for sh,t in zip(shrt,trm)]
```

With the original question in mind, keeping in mind the condition for just the starting digits,

> df.naics.loc[(df['naics'] == '^31')] = '31'

here is what I have:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'naics':['311', '311919', '3159', '331', '332', '332913']})

def str_replace2(df, s, col, term): 
    df.loc[s.astype(str).str[:2] == term, col] = term
    return df

df = str_replace2(df, df.naics, 'naics', '31')
```